# Faithful representation of Lie groups

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras

Let $G$ be a connected real Lie group such that it admits a faithful representation into the projective special linear group $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$ where $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$ is the smallest  among other projective groups where $G$ can be represented faithfully.

I have two questions:

1. If $G=R\cdot S$ is the Levi-decomposition where $R$ is the radical and $S$ is the semismple subalgebra. Then, $R\cap S=\{e\}$?
2. Is the commutator $G'$ a normal subgroup of $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$?
3. Let $\mathfrak g^{\mathbb C}$ be the complexification of the Lie algebra $\mathfrak g$ of $G$, is it also true that the corresponding complex Lie group has a faithful representation into $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each of the three points, I can provide a partial, yet incomplete, answer.

**Regarding 1.**, the following link states that $R \cap S = \{e\}$ (and $G$ is a semidirect product of $S$ and $R$) if $G$ is simply connected (without any other assumptions):

https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Lie_group

**Regarding 2.**, the commutator is a characteristic subgroup, so the answer is yes if $G$ is normal in $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$.

**Regarding 3.**, note that in the compact case, the complex Lie group associated to the complexification of the Lie algebra is the complexification of $G$, so by the universal property of the latter, we get a morphism $G_{\mathbb C} \to PSL_n(\mathbb C)$. The image of $\pi$ has a complexification in $PSL_n(\mathbb C)$ and the inverse of $\pi$ may be extended to it via the same universal property. A third application of that universal property shows that injectivity is preserved.